# Frames don't load in Tk. (Tk-Gui-Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm new to Python programming and I am doing this project for learning. My problem is, when I start the app, `MainScreen` is shown but after that other frames are not loading. These functions work seperately. `Animate` and `texting` functions work when executed on their own. I'm trying to put them together in a single app.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
from time import sleep
import serial
from Tkinter import *

FO = open("SensorValues.txt", "w+")
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
ser.open()  

data = ser.readline(5)

FO.write(data + '\n')
FO.flush()

def organizer(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()

MainScreen = Frame(root)
LiveGraph = Frame(root)
LiveLabel = Frame(root)

for frame in (MainScreen,LiveGraph,LiveLabel):
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='news')

Label(MainScreen,text = 'Choose what do you want').pack()

def animate(i):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

    sleep(1)

    dataArray = FO.split('\n')

    xar = []
    yar = []

    for eachLine in dataArray:

        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')

            xar.append(int(x))
            yar.append(int(y))

    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()

    ax1.plot(xar)
    ax2.plot(yar)
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

    plt.show()

def texting():   
    LiveLabel.config(text=data)

    root.after(1, texting)

organizer(MainScreen)

Button(MainScreen, text = 'Press for starting live graph!', width = 30, command = lambda:organizer(LiveGraph)).pack()
Button(MainScreen, text = 'Press for starting live label!', width = 30, command = lambda:organizer(LiveLabel)).pack()

Label(LiveGraph,text = '1st Table Temperature - 2nd Table Humidity').pack()

Button(LiveGraph,text = 'Stop',width = 10, command = root.destroy ).pack()
Button(LiveLabel,text = 'Stop',width = 10, command = root.destroy ).pack()

plt.show()
FO.close()
ser.close()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshots :

[image: Started comminucation and Mainscreen loaded.]

[image: Pressed Live-Graph Button]

[image: Pressed on Live-Label Button]

Comment: I tried to make the question easier to read, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: The frame is showing but your graph is not added to it. See [matplotlib docs to embed it in a tk _canvas](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_canvas_sgskip.html)

Comment: Thanks for edit and reference. It helped :) @JacquesGaudin